# Select checkboxes in table in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, gulp-protractor

I have a table and the first column of each row contains a check box, second column is contains a name. I want to check all rows and filter them if the second row contains what i  ask. If it contains select the checkbox in the first column. here is my code but it doesnt select checkbox.

```
      element.all(by.css(' table > tbody >tr')).filter(function(element, index){
            return element.getText().then(function (text) {
                return text.includes('Company');
            })
        }).first().element(by.css(' table > tbody >tr > td#checked')).click();
```

Comment: Very difficult to answer without having the relevant HTML of the table structure. Also ICYMI, Protractor is now getting deprecated. https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5502

Comment: @demouser123 it is, but I use protractor in the current project. ALso, this issue actuallty related to Js. so, you may come across the same issue in another tools